# Converting pseudocode for array minimum into Java code, using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am blanking on this exam review question, can anyone help me get started?  In findMinPos, I am confused by the three parameters, how do I access the nodes in data array? Can I use a loop even though it's a recursive method?

```
public class ArraySwapMin
{
    public static void swapMin( int[] data, int cur )  
    {   
        int min = findMinPos( data, cur, cur );
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // swap the min position value with the one in the cur position
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    } 
    /**
     * Check the nodes in "data" from position "start" to the end of the array.
     * to see if any value in this part of the array is less than the min
     * value found so far (up to the "cur" position).
     */ 
    private static int findMinPos( int[] data, int cur, int minPosSoFar )
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Compare this entry's value (if it is a valid entry) with the
        // value in the entry "minPosSoFar". If this value is less, then 
        // this entry is now the "minPosSoFar". 
        // Recurse for the rest of the array.
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


           return minPosSoFar;
    }

    /**
     * unit tester
     */
    public static void  main( String[] args )
    {
        int[] data = { 12, 3, 10, 5, 1, 8 };

        int count = 0;
        System.out.println( "++++++++++++++++ ArraySwapMin ++++++++++++++++" );
        printArray( "starting array ", data );

        for ( int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++ )
        {
            swapMin( data, i );
            printArray( "swap Min with " + i, data );
        }

    }
    public static void printArray( String label, int[] data )
    {
        System.out.print( label + ": [ " );
        for ( int i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++ )
            System.out.print( data[ i ] + ", " );
        System.out.println( data[ data.length - 1 ] + " ]" );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You've described a problem but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  What *is* your question? 2) See [Starting Writing a Program](http://home.earthlink.net/~patricia_shanahan/beginner.html) for great tips.

Comment: sorry I will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `swapMin()` you have to switch the current position with the one with the minimum.

```
public static void swapMin( int[] data, int cur )  
{   
    int min = findMinPos( data, cur, cur );

    int minValue = data[min];
    data[min] = data[cur];
    data[cur] = minValue;
}
```

The minimum will recursively determined in `findMinPos()`. The whole idea of recurseiv programming is to use the returnvalues of an inner method call instead of using a loop. What you need is an overall break condition (in your case the length of the array) and usually multiple return statements.

This one here will do the trick:

```
private static int findMinPos( int[] data, int cur, int minPosSoFar )
{
    if(cur < data.length)
    {
        if(data[cur] < data[minPosSoFar]) // set new minimum to position cur
        {
            return findMinPos(data, cur + 1, cur);
        }
        else // keep old minimum
        {
            return findMinPos(data, cur + 1, minPosSoFar);
        }
    }

    return minPosSoFar;
}
```

And since the multiple return statements in the if-else block makes the code long and messy you can shorten it like this

```
private static int findMinPos( int[] data, int cur, int minPosSoFar )
{
    if(cur < data.length)
    {
        return (data[cur] < data[minPosSoFar]) ? 
            findMinPos(data, cur + 1, cur) :
            findMinPos(data, cur + 1, minPosSoFar);
    }

    return minPosSoFar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They have given you pseudocode. Just do exactly what it says. First change the instructions to step by step.

1. Compare this entry's value (if it is a valid entry) with the value in the entry "minPosSoFar".
2. If this value is less, then this entry is now the "minPosSoFar".
3. Recurse for the rest of the array.

So:

```
private static int findMinPos( int[] data, int cur, int minPosSoFar )
{
  if (cur < data.length) { // Needed for stopping at the end of the array
    if (data[cur] < data[minPosSoFar]) { // 1.
      minPosSoFar = cur; // 2.
    }
    return findMinPos(data, cur+1, minPosSoFar); // 3.
  }
  return minPosSoFar;
}
```

Since this is for school, I don't want to do the whole thing for you, hopefully this will give you a good idea what to do.